# Determine what settings are associated with a phantom/orphan GPO object

Tags: active-directory, powershell, group-policy

I am attempting to troubleshoot an issue that is suspected to be coming from a phantom GPO object.

I found the Get-GPOMappings (https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Get-GPOMappings-Generate-09fe167c) script on technet and it identified a list of phantom GPOs. I am able to use GET-GPO and see DisplayName, owner, etc detail data.

I am unsure as to how to view what actual settings that these objects change.

Can anyone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

The actual settings are a collection of admx scripts that get pushed to endpoints.  MSFT hasn't provided a way to query the settings inside the scripts using pwsh.  There also isn't a WMI or COM object you can instantiate and leverage to gain this data.  As a result pwsh cmdlets can only provide metadata about the GPO's.

However, GPO is going the way of the dinosaur (IMHO from working in big tech).  These settings are now being maintained with DSC, Chef, Puppet, CFN, or some other desired state platform.  GPO doesn't really fit into the IaC (infrastructure as code) model.